# parsimonious - Rule 'rules' matched in its entirety, but it didn't consume all the text

Tags: python, parsing, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, parsimonious

I am making a simple parser for expressions and this is my code:

```
import parsimonious as parmon

parser = parmon.Grammar(r"""
            E = E "+" E / id
            id = "0"/"1"/"2"/"3"/"4"/"5"/"6"/"7"/"8"/"9"
    """)

code = "2+2"

print(parser.parse(code))
```

I get this error:

```
IncompleteParseError(text, node.end, self)
parsimonious.exceptions.IncompleteParseError: Rule 'rules' matched in its entirety, but it didn't consume all the text. The non-matching portion of the text begins with '/ id
            id = "0"/"1"' (line 2, column 16).
```

I have also tried Lark-parser but couldn't get to work on that either. Help appreciated.

Comment: Parsimonious' github page lists "Maybe support left-recursive rules" under "Future Directions", so I don't think left-recursion is currently supported.

Comment: Try putting spaces around the `/` operators. Or write the rule as a regex: `id = ~"[0-9]+"` (remove the `+` if you really only want to accept single-digit numbers.) Also, what @sepp2k said.

Comment: @rici that didn't work.

Comment: Which "that"? The spaces or the regex? And in what way did it "not work"?

Comment: neither space nor regex worked. Both showed the same error.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error message. I downloaded parsimonious 0.8 which gave me an error on the `E = E "+" E / id` line, at the `/`. Changing it to `E = ( E "+" E ) / id` got it to compile the grammar. I know next to nothing about parsimonious. Unless you have some emotional attachment to PEG parsing, take a look at PLY, which is a mature project.

Comment: @ParamdeepSinghObheroi: could you please mark one of the answers as answering the question if it does it for you?

Answer (score 1):

I can't offer anything wrt any of the parsers you mentioned. Have you considered [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/)?

- `id` is defined to be a one-digit numerical token.
- `Forward` indicates that `E` will be defined later in the code. (It's analogous to the use of 'forward' in procedural languages.)
- The `<<` operator inserts the definition of `E` into itself. The parentheses call for a 'match first,' meaning that the first expression in the 'or' will be applied, if possible.
- The parser is exercised within the two `print` functions.

Here's a simple parser for that kind of expression.

```
from pyparsing import *

id = Word(nums, min=1, max=1)
E = Forward()
E << (id + '+' + E | id)

code = '2 + 2'

print (E.parseString(code))

print (E.parseString('3+4+5'))
```

This codes yields this result.

```
['2', '+', '2']
['3', '+', '4', '+', '5']
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is worth to elaborate on the @rici's comment with a solution to your problem:

`E = E "+" E / id` means in fact:  `E = E "+" (E / id)` which is a non-ending recursive definition:

`E = E "+" E / id` when `E` is substituted for the right side:

`E =  (E "+" (E / id)) "+" (E / id)`, etc.

This means that although the right operand of `+` is matched right away in your example expression (picking `id` production which is the terminal character `2`) there would still be (neverending) doubts how to match the left side.

That is why the EBNF you provided is wrong and changing it to:

`E = ( E "+" E ) / id`

solves the problem.